# Merge and alias [jvisualvm] into [visualvm]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

While browsing through some [jvisualvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvisualvm) questions, I realized there's also a [visualvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualvm) tag.

Both tags are used for questions regarding VisualVM, Oracle's open source Java profiler. Some questions use either one of these tags, and some are tagged with both.

According to [VisualVM download page](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html):

> VisualVM comes in two distributions: VisualVM at GitHub and Java VisualVM as a JDK tool. VisualVM at GitHub is a bleeding-edge distribution with the latest features. To get a stable tool, use the Java VisualVM available in your Oracle JDK 8.

[jvisualvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvisualvm) is one version of VisualVM, that is distributed with Oracle's HotSpot JDK (at least that's true nowadays), so it seems it could be aliased and merged into [visualvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualvm). [visualvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualvm) carries the name of the project, so it comes as more suitable to be the main tag, and [jvisualvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvisualvm) may be a good alias (personally, I am using jvisualvm from Oracle's HotSpot distribution so intuitively came looking for [jvisualvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvisualvm) questions).

Here are some stats on both tags:

- [visualvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualvm): 520 questions, 45 followers. Tag excerpt:

  > VisualVM is a visual tool integrating several commandline JDK tools and lightweight profiling capabilities. Designed for both production and development time use, it further enhances the capability of monitoring and performance analysis for the Java SE platform.
- [jvisualvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvisualvm): 313 questions, 33 followers. Tag excerpt:

  > jvisualvm is a Java Virtual Machine monitoring, troubleshooting and profiling tool. It is part of Oracle/Sun JDK since JDK 6 update 7 and is based on open-source project VisualVM.